# How can i send my template values to database using Jquery, Ajax in django?

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django, sqlite

1.jquery

```
    $(textbox).on('click','.save',function(e){ 
          e.preventDefault();
        var x = $('#input_msg').val();
        $.ajax({
          url:'newpostx/',
           type: $(this).attr('method'), 
           data: x,
           headers:{
              'X-CSRFToken':'{{csrf_token}}'
           }
         }).done(function(msg) {
            document.location = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/newpostx/"
             
            alert("save data")


          }).fail(function(err){
              alert('no data was saved')
       })
          
   });
```

2. home.html

   ```
    $(container).on('click','.show', function () {     //On click of
        link, textbox will open

                  console.log(count[1])
                    msg_bubble = 1;
                    $("div.popup").show();
                    var num = $(this).attr('value');
                    console.log(num,'num')
                    $(textbox).append('Grid No_ '+ num
        +'Bot MessagesType any text
        here  Add Message BubbleSelect InputText
        InputButtonsStar RatingsCalendar &
        TimeImage/File
        InputSelect User Input:
        Name
        -->Type Input:
   File
        UploadTake PhotoFile Upload & Take
        PhotoButton
     Add ButtonNumber of
        stars:
   345Steps in
        stars:
   0.51Type Input:
   NameFull
        NameEmailMobilePasswordCustom
        TextCalendarData Limitation
        TypeAbsolute DateRelative
        DateMin Date
   Max
        Date
   TimeAppointment
        Duration15 minutes30
        minutes1 hour2
        hourStart Time
   09:00 AM10:00
        AM11:00 AM12:00
        AMEnd Time
   09:00
        AM10:00 AM11:00
        AM12:00
        AMCancelSave')
                       $("#input_msg").val()
                      $("#input_msg"+num).text(window.localStorage.getItem(key+num))
                      console.log(count[num-1])

                      for(var i=2; iType any text
        here');
                      $(".container_inside").append(structure);
                      $("#add_msg_"+num+i).text(window.localStorage.getItem(num+i));

                    }

                });
   ```

3.views.py

```
    def post_new(request):
     if request.method == "POST":
      
        new_poll= text() #call model object
        d= request.POST
        new_poll.message= d['message']
        
        new_poll.save()
        print(new_poll)
        return render(request, "loggedin.html")
```

4.models.py

```
class text(models.Model):
    message = models.TextField(max_length=250)
    time = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
```

5.urls.py

```
  path('newpostx/',views.post_new,name='post_new'),
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are trying to send single value, so jQuery maps sent variable name to 'x' (so you get `{'x': $('#input_msg').val()}` in `request.POST`).
To solve that you need to overwrite your `data` attribute in `AJAX` call.

So you change this line:

`data: x`

In jQuery/JavaScript file to:

`data: {'message': x}`

And it should work. Also note that your first alert won't work because you change `document.location` and thus you change your current site before executing `alert()` call.

Comment: thanks its worked, but still i am getting an error related to views.py in which i am getting MultiValueDictKeyError at /newpostx/ this error.

Comment: def post_new(request):
     if request.method == "GET":
      
        new_poll= text() #call model object
        d= request.GET
        new_poll.message= d['message']
        
        new_poll.save()
        #print(new_poll)
        return render(request, "loggedin.html")

Comment: Can you post how do you sent your `data` attribute in the AJAX call? I'm not really sure if you're sending correct `{key: variable}` statement.

Comment: $(textbox).on('click','.save',function(e){ e.preventDefault(); var x = $('#input_msg').val() console.log(x);$.ajax({url:'',
           type: $(this).attr('method'), 
         
           data:{ message : $('#input_msg').val(),},
           contentType: false,
           cache: false,
           processData: false,
           headers:{
              'X-CSRFToken':'{{csrf_token}}'
           }
      }).done(function(key, value) {
          document.location = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/newpostx/"
      alert("save data") }).fail(function(err){) }) });

Comment: For me it should work, not sure what you did wrong... I don't know also why you did change your method from POST to GET, are you sure that your code is correct?

Comment: no i am not sure thats why i just want a help to run my code in correct way.

Comment: Try to print `request.GET` or either `request.POST` and check if correct data is here. Also update your question with existing code.

Comment: Also `data: {message : $('#input_msg').val(),},` should be rewritten as `data: {message : $('#input_msg').val()},` - I am not really sure if javascript does not interpret additional comma as array separator.